# Digital Ocean ENV Variables - .env file, ENV Variables, or something else?

Tags: security, devops, digital-ocean

Does Digital Ocean have something similar to Credstash or AWS Secrets Manager (both AWS services)?

Trying to decide on the most secure way to store environmental variables with sensitive information (like database access codes, for example).

Locally, I have .env file that is named in my .gitignore to prevent it being version controlled.

If just in a .env file or environment variables, what’s the best way to keep that secure for the app to run appropriately?

Much appreciated :)

Cheers

ADDITIONAL INFO:

I have a fullstack SPA (MongoDB, Node, React, Express) on the digital ocean droplet.

Answer (score -1):

This is quite a loaded question to get this done right, and implementation cost depends on what your risk tolerance is and a variety of other things (i.e. threat modeling). Below are just some things to consider.

- At the very minimum, you're going to want to ensure your sensitive configuration is *encrypted at rest* on the disk and assess whether this is going to end up in your backups as well, as part of infrastructure management, etc. Even if you used a third party system for credential management, you're still going to be maintaining API credentials on your host to connect to that system, else it will still be accessible locally via mount, or in-memory, etc.
- You have to also consider how strings might or might not be garbage collected/copied in memory and what your risk tolerance is there.
- It also goes without saying that part of your post-commit/CI should explicitly ensure file permissions are being set correctly as intended over your sensitive configuration files (i.e. `chmod 0400`).
- You also want to run through an application compromise scenario where an attacker is able to read the file system (not memory, and not application code injection) with your application. So do a `su` to impersonate your application process' user on the host to see what it can actually do with your config file. If it's encrypted at rest and is unable to discover the decryption keys or decrypt it altogether, well you're probably in a better place than 99% of WordPress websites out there.

There's definitely more to discuss, but that should get you started. You might also consider popping over to https://security.stackexchange.com/ with this question.

Best wishes!

Comment: Great feedback, thank you. For encrypting at rest, I assume something standard like gpg? Will the web application need to locally decrypt every time it calls on those variables?

Comment: Unfortunately, what I'm able to tell you probably won't make it easier for you, but you should give this Windows-specific configuration a serious look: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/53tyfkaw%28v%3dvs.140%29 (link updated with walkthrough ToC page)

Comment: It outlines a process by which .NET developers are able to inherit some OS-level security when set up correctly: creating a RSA key container, setting appropriate permissions for who can actually read it, and requiring 0 change to the developer's code because `ConfigurationManager` is capable of detecting encrypted sections and invoking decryption if it finds it (else reads it in as-is). Values are read once, then remain in memory until GC. Lot of models here to consider in your own implementation.

Comment: Then see how you can apply those models to your implementation; sensitive information encrypted at rest, file with appropriate permissions, in-memory caching of recently decrypted settings to mitigate CPU, and yes of course, tried and tested standard encryption [library]. Not all AES implementations are the same, for example; some are academic use only, subject to timing attacks, etc. Also good introductory reading on encryption: https://github.com/rdev5/crypto-wrapper/wiki/Crypto-Implementation-%28DRAFT%29

Comment: Another interesting model pertaining to encrypted configs is Puppet's Hiera-eYaml: https://puppet.com/blog/encrypt-your-data-using-hiera-eyaml/. Again, you're going to be augmenting your CI/workflow with decrypt-edit-encrypt-load detail each time you want to change something, etc. But same rules apply. Oh, and see if you can keep your `.env` file out of source control if you can code your app to look elsewhere, and deploy configs separately. Hopefully that will help guide what you should be looking for in your own stack. Best wishes! Let me know if you need anything else :)

Comment: Deployed in Linux, so probably can't use the windows specific one. I'll dig around on if there is something similar in linux-land (almost certainly is). 

Thank you for the comments and feedback! 
Have a bit to read on and consider.